# jquery menu; select specific item using a function

Tags: jquery, menu

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/JhcYu/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

         $(function() {

            $("#tabs, #tabs2").tabs();

            $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);

            $('#alt2 li').click(function(e) {

                if($(this).find('>ul').is(':visible'))
                     $(this).find('>span').html('+');
                else
                     $(this).find('>span').html('-');        


                $(this).find('>ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(150, "swing")
            /*    .end().siblings().find('ul').slideUp().closest('li')    */
                .find('>span').html('+');


                $('#alt2 li').each(function(){
                    $(this).css({ 'font-weight' : 'normal'  });
                });

                $(this).css({ 'font-weight' : 'bold' }).children().css({ 'font-weight' : 'normal' });

                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            $('#alt2 li').each(function(i, val){

                var children = $(val).find('ul li');

                if(children.size() > 0)
                    $(val).prepend('<span>+</span>');


            });

            function selectListitemByText(listitemText) {

                $('#alt2 li').each(function(i, val){

                    var currentListitemText = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();

                    if(currentListitemText == listitemText) {

                        //$(val)...
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }





        });

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">


        body { font: 12px Verdana; }

        .ui-tabs-nav { background: transparent; border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;  }
        .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav { padding: 0.2em 0 0; }
        .ui-widget-content { border: 0; }
        .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { border: 1px solid #aaa; border-width: 1px; border-top: 0;}
        .ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-br { border-radius: 0; }

        #tabs-2 { padding: 0; }

        #alt2 { width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; }
        #alt2 ul { list-style: none; }
        #alt2 ul ul { display: none; }
        #alt2 li { cursor: pointer; margin: 5px; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="alt2">

    <ul>
        <li>
            System Audit
            <ul>
                <li >Site and Contacts</li>
                <li>Current Licenses</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Expected Result
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Control System Information
                    <ul>
                        <li>ABB Contacts</li>
                        <li>Channel Partner Contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>Machine ID's</li>
                <li>Current Licenses</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Quotation
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem</li>
                <li>Ipsum</li>
                <li>Result</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want a function, "selectListitemByText", that selects a listitem at any depth. The functionality should remain the same (+ turns in to - when expended, font+weight: bold etc). Ive started writing the function but im not really sure how to select the correct parents and children.

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using jstree?  Not that it would help you with your function, but you seem to be reinventing a wheel that is likely to become the foundation of the official jQuery UI tree widget.  If you used jstree, once you found your selected node, you could simply use the jstree open method and it would take care of all the details of displaying the open node.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i prefer using my own code in this case,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a function which works pretty well, but I had to had some stuff to your code.

See the comments in this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/59tKg/5/

Comment: Nice, ive accepted the answers. The only problem is that it doesnt work for the top level :)

Comment: And if i type "Current Licenses", it expands the first item (System Audit) as well.

Comment: I've fixed the first problem, the function compares the `<li>` text, and top levels elements' `text()` also includes all the child elements' text. See the comments ! ([link updated](http://jsfiddle.net/59tKg/5/))

Comment: About "Current Licenses", the problem is that there are 2 `<li>` containing this exact text. I've changed the function so that it only selects the last corresponding `<li>` found, since you can only have one unique `<li>` selected

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to select the item containing the given text? Here you go.

```
 selectListitemByText(text) {
     $('#alt2').find('li:contains('+text+')');
 }
```